# How to List Jobs with the REST API?

Tags: rest-api, job, jobs

My problem is that I can't list job postings from Sage People API.

I managed to authorize my web application and get an access token. Now I only need to know the correct way to consume the API.

What I have tried so far is:

**--All resource URIs (it took so much time to find them indeed)--**

**Request:**

https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v45.0/

**Response:**

{
    "tooling": "/services/data/v45.0/tooling",
    "metadata": "/services/data/v45.0/metadata",
    "eclair": "/services/data/v45.0/eclair",
    "folders": "/services/data/v45.0/folders",
    "prechatForms": "/services/data/v45.0/prechatForms",
    "chatter": "/services/data/v45.0/chatter",
    "tabs": "/services/data/v45.0/tabs",
    "appMenu": "/services/data/v45.0/appMenu",
    "quickActions": "/services/data/v45.0/quickActions",
    "queryAll": "/services/data/v45.0/queryAll",
    "commerce": "/services/data/v45.0/commerce",
    "wave": "/services/data/v45.0/wave",
    "iot": "/services/data/v45.0/iot",
    "analytics": "/services/data/v45.0/analytics",
    "search": "/services/data/v45.0/search",
    "identity": "https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D0O000000sv28UAA/0050O000009j9tMQAQ",
    "composite": "/services/data/v45.0/composite",
    "parameterizedSearch": "/services/data/v45.0/parameterizedSearch",
    "fingerprint": "/services/data/v45.0/fingerprint",
    "theme": "/services/data/v45.0/theme",
    "nouns": "/services/data/v45.0/nouns",
    "event": "/services/data/v45.0/event",
    "serviceTemplates": "/services/data/v45.0/serviceTemplates",
    "recent": "/services/data/v45.0/recent",
    "connect": "/services/data/v45.0/connect",
    "licensing": "/services/data/v45.0/licensing",
    "limits": "/services/data/v45.0/limits",
    "process": "/services/data/v45.0/process",
    "dedupe": "/services/data/v45.0/dedupe",
    "async-queries": "/services/data/v45.0/async-queries",
    "query": "/services/data/v45.0/query",
    "jobs": "/services/data/v45.0/jobs",
    "emailConnect": "/services/data/v45.0/emailConnect",
    "consent": "/services/data/v45.0/consent",
    "compactLayouts": "/services/data/v45.0/compactLayouts",
    "sobjects": "/services/data/v45.0/sobjects",
    "actions": "/services/data/v45.0/actions",
    "support": "/services/data/v45.0/support"
}

**--Trial #1 to list all jobs--**

**Request (source: above API call response):**

https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v45.0/jobs

**Response:**

{
    "ingest": "services/data/v45.0/jobs/ingest"
}

**--Trial #2 to list all jobs--**

**Request (source: Bulk API 2.0 >  Get All Jobs https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_bulk_v2.meta/api_bulk_v2/get_all_jobs.htm):**

https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v45.0/jobs/ingest

**Response:**

[
    {
        "errorCode": "NOT_FOUND",
        "message": "The requested resource does not exist"
    }
]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't received any response here, nor at developer.salesforce.com/forums so far and this is disappointing and surprising to me.

Whatever, here is my solution with a guide inside:

https://github.com/kahramanbayraktar/sage-people-api

https://github.com/kahramanbayraktar/sage-people-api/blob/master/how-to-use-sage-people-api